# What is the most efficient way to create multiple records in several tables with one API call (sequelize/postgres/node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have to store data across several separate tables in Postgres in one API call. I can call each of these separately but I'd like to know how to do this the most efficient way. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

For example:

```
function create(req, res, next) {
    let people = []
    Male.create({
        name: 'Smith',
        firstname: 'John'
    }).then(john => {
        people.push(john),
            console.log(john.get({
                plain: true
            }))
    })

    Female.create({
        name: 'Smith',
        firstname: 'Jane'
    }).then(jane => {
        people.push(jane),
            console.log(jane.get({
                plain: true
            }))
    })

    Child.create({
        name: 'Smith',
        firstname: 'JayJay'
    }).then(jayjay => {
        people.push(jayjay),
            console.log(jayjay.get({
                plain: true
            }))
    })
    res.send(people[0])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call a postgres procedure , for example :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_family(father_name varchar(100), mother_name varchar(100), child_name varchar(100))
LANGUAGE plpgsql    
AS $$

BEGIN
Insert into father ( name ) values ( father_name ) ;
insert into mother ( name ) values ( mother_name ) ;
insert into child  ( name ) values ( child_name  ) ;
end
```

Comment: wouldn't that take away from using an ORM?

Comment: Yes , it would , but with ORM is hard to do this :) Choose the best tool, don't try to use one tool for all stuff .